# Change the folder where screenshots are saved

Tags: release-freya, screenshot

When taking a screenshot using <kbd>prt sc</kbd> the screenshot is saved to the pictures folder. Instead of saving them in pictures I would like them to be saved to another folder instead.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reuse the answer [from here](https://askubuntu.com/a/134469/79547), with small changes

### Via GUI

1. Install [dconf-editor](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools)

   - From the command line, run the command `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`
   - Or click here to install from the Ubuntu Software Center:

     [Install via the software center http://hostmar.co/software-banner](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-editor)
2. Press <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type `dconf-editor`
3. Go to `org` -> `gnome` -> `gnome-screenshot`
4. At "auto-save-directory" type the desired directory in the following format: `file:///home/user/Desktop/`

   [image: name: auto-save-directory, value: file:///full/path/]

   A tip for anyone who is using the configuration editor in unity: click on the arrow to the left the `org` text to expand it.

### Via Terminal

Simply run this command, replacing the path with your preferred directory.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory "file:///home/$USER/Downloads/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I managed to get screenshots (taken with the Print key) stored in the Downloads folder. Bit of a cheat but works. elementary OS 5.1 Hera.

```
$ cd ~/Pictures
$ rmdir Screenshots
$ ln -s ~/Downloads Screenshots
```

Answer (score 1):

Please not that with the next release of Gala screenshots will be stored in a `~/Pictures/Screenshots/` folder.
Gala is elementary OS's window manager and the thing that's responsible for taking screenshots.
This was fixed in this PR: https://github.com/elementary/gala/pull/459
Currently we're on Gala version 0.3.2.