# How do I change the folder where screenshots are saved?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

Currently, when I take a screenshot using the shortcut keys (`PrtSc`, `Shift`+`PrtSc`, etc.), it is always saved to ~/Pictures. I would like it to save to ~/Pictures/Screenshots.

Using dconf-editor, I have tried setting `io.elementary.screenshot-tool folder-dir` to:

- ~/Pictures/Screenshots/
- /home/USER/Pictures/Screenshots/
- file:///home/USER/Pictures/Screenshots/

I have also tried omitting the slash at the end and putting the string in single and double quotes, and logging out/restarting after changing the setting. None of this works.

Is there actually a way to do this?

(Note: [this previous question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/5384/change-the-folder-where-screenshots-are-saved) is about gnome-screenshot, a different program than screenshot-tool.)

**Update:** this problem was fixed as of the latest Gala release! Many thanks to the hardworking developers.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix this myself but I don't believe there is a simple way. However, there is a workaround that I'm using.

1. set your folder dir in dconf-editor (as you already did)
2. map custom command `io.elementary.screenshot-tool` to `Print` button using the `keyboard settings`

That's it. Now each time you hit `Print` button you'll get the `screenshot-tool` opened, but most importantly, the app will have you folder dir from `gsettings` set as default.

Comment: Thank you, but I find using just the shortcut keys is a lot quicker than opening the program, then clicking a radio button, etc.

Comment: Same here @aleck but unfortunately without opening the program, folder-dir in gsettings has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that with the latest release of Gala screenshots will be stored in a `~/Pictures/Screenshots/` folder.
This is Gala version `0.3.2~r688+pkg45~ubuntu5.0.1` released on 2019-02-25.
Gala is elementary OS's window manager and the thing that's responsible for taking screenshots.
This was fixed in this PR: https://github.com/elementary/gala/pull/459

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! Do you know when the next version will be released?

Comment: There was a new release, made on 2019-02-25 as far as I understand it.