# How to change default folder for saving screenshots?

Tags: screenshot, folder, default

### The Issue

How do I change the default folder where (whole screen) screenshots are saved when `print` key is pressed?

By default, it is set to `~/Pictures/Screenshots/` but I want to specify another path.

#### A failed attempt

With `dconf-editor`, I specified the value of `folder-dir` to a different path but it didn't work:

[image]

Apparently, `folder-dir` sets the default folder path which appears in the following dialog box after a screenshot is taken using `screenshot` app:

[image]

#### An outdated answer

This answer (https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/5470/20018) is outdated since `gnome-screenshot` is not being used for current elementary OS 5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the screenshot app location and the one of the <kbd>prt sc</kbd> button command are different. In order to achieve what you need I can recommend you to use the Files application, navigate to the parrent folder of the one you want to store the screenshots automatically, right click on the folder you want the screenshots to be stored and select **Copy as Link**. Open the Pictures folder, right click inside, choose **Paste Link** there and **rename** the link to Screenshots.